# How to ignore items added for grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I created jQuery autocomplete. Data that is returned is of multiple categories so I want to add grouping. I add group name whenever new group is found because my data is sorted. I do this in _renderMenu() method. It shows ok, but added elements behave like ordinary items, so they have focus and select event which I don't want. How can I convince autocomplete that it will ignore all elements with class 'ui-autocomplete-category'?

```
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchData", "Account", new {Area = ""})',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { searchString: $("#searchInput").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        console.log(item);
                        return {
                            label: item.DisplayName, value: item.EntityInstanceId + "," + item.EntityId, categoryName: item.EntityDisplayName
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            })
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                return false;
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        delay: 400,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                return false;
            }
            //do something
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li style='margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px; margin-bottom: 3px;'></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a style='color: #3e9645; font-family: Segoe UI;'>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
        };

    $("#searchInput").autocomplete().data("autocomplete")._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
        var that = this;
        var currentEntity = "";
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            var itemEntity = item.value.split(",")[1];
            if (currentEntity !== itemEntity) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.categoryName + "</li>");
                console.log(item);
                currentEntity = itemEntity;
            }

            that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, had to add this code:

```
create: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).data('ui-autocomplete').menu.options.items = "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)";
}
```

So that autocomplete now ignores all element with this class